# How to find the closest element to the current position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a document with several sections like this:

```
<div class='section' id='sec1'>
    lalala
    lalala
    lalala
</div>

<div class='section' id='sec2'>
    lalala
    lalala
    lalala
</div>

<div class='section' id='sec3'>
    lalala
    lalala
    lalala
</div>

<div class='section' id='sec4'>
    lalala
    lalala
    lalala
</div>
```

How do I grab the closest `<div.section>` to the current scroll position (presumably, this would equate to the section that the reader is currently looking at)?

Comment: Besides using hover you could take the scroll position and subtract the height of each '.section' from it till it is 0 or less. That will be increasingly difficult with the more you have wrapping these divs.

Comment: There is a fair amount wrapped around these divs, and a lot inside it (it's the HTML output from docbook)

Comment: gizmovation gives a better approach below anyways

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(el).postion().top` to figure out how far the element is from the top of the screen after scrolling.

You can then use this information to manipulate the element as desired.

Here is a working jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/x8FDU/

Comment: Hi guys,
I was wondering if this could be achieved with plain JavaScript as well?

Answer (score -5):

Whenever you hover an element the `mousemove` event tells you which element you're hovering over.

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.target
    /*
        the target in click/hover events
        is the element that the event was
        triggered on.
    */
});
```

One drawback may be the fact `e.target` will give you the element with the highest `z-index` -- the one in the top-most layer -- so if you have an overlay above your text it will give you the overlay not the text `div`.

Comment: Please add more clarification on your answer and explain why it works.

Comment: @johannes -- the explanation in the comment is pretty clear IMO. Whenever you hover an element the `mousemove` event tells you which element you're hovering over.