# jQuery scroll from element to element to element and factor in page scroll

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am trying to make a fixed navigation that lets you scroll between elements on a page and keeps count of where you are on the page. I have seen a couple examples, to which I modified slightly, but haven't been able to get any to work properly. My latest attempt works fine with when you toggle between the previous/next buttons to get from section to section, but I want to take into account where the user is on the page. For example, if I click on the next button two times, the count is set to 2, and it takes me to the second section on the page. Then if I click the previous button once, the count is set to 1, and it takes me the first section on the page. Now if I scroll down towards the middle of the page (using the browser scrollbar), and hit the next button, the count is set to 3 and it takes me to the second section on page. I want it so that it takes me to the next visible section on the page. I need a way to detect what section the user is currently on and factor that in to my logic so that someone can seamlessly navigate through the page using either their scrollbar or this fixed navigation. How can I achieve this?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/picitelli/fCLKm/

**JS**

```
function scrollTo(el) {

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, 500);

}

var scroller = $('.scroller'),
    scrollNext = scroller.find('.next'),
    scrollPrev = scroller.find('.prev'),
    count = 0,
    sectionCounter = $('.section').length;

scrollNext.on("click", function() {

    if (count < sectionCounter && count !== sectionCounter) {
        count++;
        scrollTo('.section:eq(' + count + ')');
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    console.log(count);

});

scrollPrev.on("click", function() {

    if (count > 0) {
        count--;
        scrollTo('.section:eq(' + count + ')');
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

    console.log(count);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroller">
    <span class="prev">Previous</span>
    <span class="next">Next</span>
</div>

<div class="content">Lorem ipsum some content...</div>

<div class="section">A</div>
<div class="section">B</div>
<div class="section">C</div>
<div class="section">D</div>
<div class="section">E</div>
<div class="section">F</div>
<div class="section">G</div>
<div class="section">H</div>
<div class="section">I</div>
<div class="section">J</div>
<div class="section">K</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    padding: 20px;
}
.section {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.section:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccc;
}
.scroller {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.scroller span {
    background: #fff;
    color: #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
.scroller span:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.scroller span.prev {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
```

Any feedback/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eventually I figured out a way for this to work.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/picitelli/Tfbb3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/picitelli/Tfbb3/

**New JS**

```
function scrollTo(el) {

  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
  }, 500);

}

var scroller = $('.scroller'),
    scrollPrev = scroller.find('.prev'),
    scrollNext = scroller.find('.next'),
    section = $('.section'),
    position = -1;

// add data count to each section
section.each(function(index) {

    $(this).attr('data-count', index);

});

// next click through scrolling
scrollNext.on('click', function() {

    if (position < section.length - 1) {

      position++;

      scrollTo(section[position]);

    }

});

// prev click through scrolling
scrollPrev.on('click', function() {

    if (position > 0) {

      position--;

      scrollTo(section[position]);

    }

});

// page scroll position detection
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    section.each(function() {

        var top = $(this).offset().top,
            bottom = top + $(this).height();

        if(currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {

            var sectionCount = $(this).attr('data-count');

            position = sectionCount;

        }

     });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of keeping a count,  just scroll to the nearest section closest to the window top position when scrolling down or up, when no section is in perfect position to the window top position.  And if it is, just scroll to the section one above or below the one you are on.  Take a look at this [How to find the closest element to the current position with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760567/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-the-current-position-with-jquery)