# How do I determine background color of visible underlying element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a fixed position 'go to top' `<a>` which sticks to the bottom of the page as the user scrolls. It's in the footer DIV of the page like so:

```
.pagedown div a { position: fixed; margin-left: 8px;  margin-top: 50px; width: 44px; height: 40px; color: #bd1300; background: none;}

<div class="footer"><a id="gototop" title="Go to top!" href="#">^</a></div>
```

Using jQuery or JS I would like to be able to change the color of the `<a>` based on the true underlying background color. So far, I've looked here:

[How do I detect the inherited background-color of an element using jQuery/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259815/how-do-i-detect-the-inherited-background-color-of-an-element-using-jquery-js)

This code doesn't seem to work for my use case. Perhaps since the `<a>` in question is not really 'inside of' the rest of the page DOM as it scrolls by?

So: is there a way to detect the -true- underlying background color (ie. the background color the user would actually see in the viewport)?

Comment: The problem is that there is no "THE background" for things like that. With fixed or absolute positioning, your <a> may be positioned half on one <div> and half on another with a different background color.

Comment: OK. Then is it possible to determine 'THE background' at a particular x/y position in the current Viewport? IOW: I know that my fixed position <a> is always at the bottom left, so can I determine the 'true' background color at that x/y coordinate on the screen?

Comment: Then the question becomes, "how to find the element from the window position", and the answer is, I'm not sure. I searched, but other than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10760683/1016716) which loops over all the elements in the body (which can be time consuming if you have a large document), there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: I guess one would need to ask "How do I find which elements are present (and which is at the lowest z-index) at the current x/y position of the viewport?"

Answer (score 3):

Support is not great (no IE) but you can use CSS for this.

[**mix-blend-mode @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
.footer {
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 100px
}
a {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
body {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"><a class="gototop" title="Go to top!" href="#">^</a>
</div>
```

```css
.footer {
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 100px
}
a {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
body {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"><a class="gototop" title="Go to top!" href="#">^</a>
</div>
```

Comment: But it gives you no control over the 'mixed' color, right? You're at the mercy of the underlying <div>. That's not great for me.

Comment: Actually 'luminosity' seems to be useful--makes a nice neutral gray. Not ideal, but if I can't get an answer to my original question, I'll likely use this.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

It returns the computed style of the element you give it.

**EDIT:** The background color property was returning transparent, so I wrote a recursive background color search function that circumvents this behavior.

```js
function getBGColor(el) {
    var s = getComputedStyle(el),
        b = s.backgroundColor,
        e = el;
    if ((b === "transparent" || b === "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" || b === "rgba(255,255,255,0)") && e.parentNode !== null)
        b = getBGColor(e.parentNode);
    return b;
}

document.getElementById("o").innerHTML = "Background Color: " + getBGColor(document.getElementById('gototop'));
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: lavender;
}
a {
  color: #bd1300;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="gototop" title="Go to top!" href="#">^</a>
</div>

<div id="o"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It always returns 'transparent'. My guess is that this is because the <a> has no background property itself?

Comment: @jchwebdev Right; since the default background color is transparent/none, you'll need to set `background: inherit` on the `a`, or check the background color of one of its parents.

Comment: Still not working. If I use 'inherit' it returns the backgroundColor for the body tag... which is not necessarily the -visible- background. (Since there may be many other <divs> on top of that, of course.) I need to know the background color of the -visible- background color. What am I missing?

Comment: Still always returns 'transparent'. Using Firefox on Windows 8.

Comment: Windows 8. Returns rgba(255,255,255,0) for Chrome and IE.