# Change text color based on the background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to dynamically change the text color based on the background color using CSS, or JS if it's not possible with CSS? I have a image that comes under the text. My text color is white, but the image has a white shape on. And when text goes above the white shape, I need to change the text color in a darker color.

HTML:

```
<div class="biography">
            <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/c09zw94jp/author_photo.png" alt="author" class="bio-img">
            <div class="biography-text">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <br>
                    Vestibulum pellentesque auctor quam a sollicitudin.<br>
                    Pellentesque accumsan a sem eget dictum.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Morbi dictum lorem tortor, id consequat libero gravida ut.<br>
Nullam dictum sed massa et bibendum.
                </p>
                <p>Praesent sed dui mattis, dictum urna sit amet, imperdiet purus.</p>
                <p> Suspendisse potenti.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #7ccbe6;
}
.biography {
    min-height: 410px;
}
.biography .biography-text {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -420px;
    padding: 82px 130px 0 380px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.biography-text {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obRKEy) to see the better picture.

Comment: Related -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443187/how-do-i-determine-background-color-of-visible-underlying-element/35444374#35444374

Answer (score 7):

I do realize you are looking for a JS solution. However, if anyone wants a css solution here is a solution 
http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/JNwvyL

```
$bg-color: black;  // This can change
$white : #fff;
$black : #000;

@function set-text-color($color) {
    @if (lightness( $color ) > 50) {
      @return $black; // Lighter color, return black
    }
    @else {
      @return $white; // Darker color, return white
    }
}

.text--color {
    background: $bg-color;
    color: set-text-color($bg-color);
}

// this is here just for demon purpose
.text {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


<p class="text text--color">I change in color</p>
```

Comment: True. I did not notice you want css solution.

Comment: @Petroff In css editor (on CodePen) you can see compiled css easily, just click on arrow button (_top right corner of css editor_) and click on `View Compiled CSS`.

Comment: That's compiled to that specific color, it didn't work as a "change text color based on the background color"

Answer (score 6):

**Probably you need this:**

[Change text color based on brightness of the covered background area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867545/change-text-color-based-on-brightness-of-the-covered-background-area)

```
var rgb = [255, 0, 0];

setInterval(function() {
  var c = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
  var o = Math.round(((parseInt(rgb[0]) * 299) + (parseInt(rgb[1]) * 587) + (parseInt(rgb[2]) * 114)) / 1000);
  (o > 125) ? $('#bg').css('color', 'black'): $('#bg').css('color', 'white'); //http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast
  $('#bg').css('background-color', c);
  rgb[0] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  rgb[1] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  rgb[2] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
}, 1000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VTnZ/2/)

---

**Updated:**

Use this example on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VTnZ/2/)**, just change `background color`

Comment: I do not see a way how I can implement this in my example? Can you help out if you see this as a solution?

Comment: It's not working for me, can you try it on my example? [Link here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obRKEy)

Answer (score 5):

For this kind of problem I'd use a pure CSS solution to outline the text...

```
.biography-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #333,
        -1px -1px 0 #333,
        1px -1px 0 #333,
        -1px 1px 0 #333,
        2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

Change the `letter-spacing` and the final directive of the `text-shadow` property according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve this. You could render the image on a (hidden) canvas and parse the image colors to know which color the text should be. You could also do the same with php and pre process the image color information.

I also found this JavaScript library that could help you: http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/. (You could wrap each letter in a span element to determine the right color to use per letter.)