# Menu item colors not changing properly when I scroll down to a specific section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I get each menu item highlighted to it's own color as I scroll to it's section in my WordPress site?
Eg: If I scroll down to about section, the about menu item should change color. If I scroll to contacts section, the menu item should change to a different color and obviously ABOUT should dehighlight immediately.

At the moment, when I scroll down 150px, the menu get fixed to the top. Then as I scroll down to about section, the menu item gets bold, when go to another section, the respective menu item will turn bold immediately and obviously the about menu item dehighlights.

```
var num = 150; //number of pixels before modifying styles
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');                       
        } else {
            $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');        
        }
    });    
    $("nav ul li a").addClass("marker");

    var navLinks = $('nav ul li a'),
    navH = $('nav').height(),
    section = $('section'),
    documentEl = $(document);        
    documentEl.on('scroll', function() {            
        var currentScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();            
        section.each(function() {
           var self = $(this);
           if (self.offset().top < (currentScrollPos + navH ) && (currentScrollPos + navH) < (self.offset().top + self.outerHeight())) {
               var targetClass = '.' +self.attr('class') + 'marker';
               navLinks.removeClass('active');
               $(targetClass).addClass('active'); 
           }                
        });            
    });
```

Now for the colors, I added this snippet to the first function but the colors only change when I click on each menu item more than once.

```
$("a.marker.active:contains(About)").addClass('item-2');        
$("a.marker.active:contains(Products)").addClass('item-3');
$("a.marker.active:contains(Scent)").addClass('item-4');
$("a.marker.active:contains(Clients)").addClass('item-5');
$("a.marker.active:contains(Contact)").addClass('item-6');
```

Any different way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        $('.toggle-menu').each(function() {
            var post = $(this);
            var position = post.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            
            if (position <= 0) {
                post.addClass('selected');
              var theID = $(this).attr('id');
              $('nav li a').removeClass('active');
              $('#nav-'+theID).addClass('active');
            } else {
                post.removeClass('selected');
            }
        });        
    });
```

```css
.active {
color: red;
}

#nav-about.active {
color: green;
}

#nav-products.active {
color: gray;
}

#nav-scent.active {
color: yellow;
}
header {
position: relative;}
nav {
position: absolute;
display:block;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;}
nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 10px;}

section {
padding:150px;
border-top:1px solid red;}

.selected {
font-weigt: 600;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a class="active" id="nav-about" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav-products" href="#products">Products</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav-scent" href="#scent">Scent</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav-clients" href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</header>

<section class="toggle-menu" id="about">
 <div class="wrap">
  About
 </div>
</section>

<section class="toggle-menu" id="products">
 <div class="wrap">
  Products
 </div>
</section>

<section class="toggle-menu" id="scent">
 <div class="wrap">
  Scent
 </div>
</section>

<section class="toggle-menu" id="clients">
 <div class="wrap">
  Clients
 </div>
</section>
```

Something like this?

Comment: Not really, the events should happen on scroll,not mouseenter.And also, each menu item should have it's own color, instead of one color for all which in this case is red.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Changed function to work on scroll, something wrong going with NAV position:absolute;but code should work. copied code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760567/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-the-current-position-with-jquery