# How to get the ID of a form while scrolling through a document of forms

Tags: javascript

I have a form container that holds many forms stacked on top of each other.  I want to get the ID of the form closest to the scroll position as the user scrolls through the forms.  I have tried using

```
let element = document.elementFromPoint(left, top);
let id = element.id;
```

I have also tried

```
let id = element.getAttribute('id');
```

All I get is an empty string, even though each form as a unique ID.

Here is my HTML code for the container

```
<div class="centred" id="form-container">

    <%@ include file="your-details-form.jsp" %>

    <%@ include file="spouse-details-form.jsp" %>

    <%@ include file="your-superannuation-form.jsp" %>

</div>
```

Here is the code for the first form.  The other forms are similar and all have a unique id.

```
<%@ include file ="datepicker.jsp" %>
<form class="main-form" id="your-details-form" method="post" action="">

  <div>
    <div class="form-heading">Your Details</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="required-before form-text center-text mandatory-star" id="your-details-top-message">denotes
      mandatory field</label>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <!-- DATE OF BIRTH -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="date-of-birth" class="form-text required">Date of Birth</label>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input type="date" class="form-text" id="date-of-birth" name="date-of-birth" required
                   aria-required="true" title="" placeholder="  dd/mm/yyyy">
            <div id="date-of-birth-icon-div" class="icon-div">
                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt details-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <small></small>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ARE YOU SINGLE -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="are-you-single-list" class="form-text">Are you single?</label>
          <div class="yes-no-buttons-container">
            <ul id="are-you-single-list" class="yes-no-buttons-list">
              <li class="left-button">
                <a id="yes-single-button" class="button-text">Yes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="right-button">
                <a id="no-single-button" class="button-text">No</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <small></small>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
      <!-- ARE YOU ALREADY RETIRED -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="are-you-already-retired-list" class="form-text">Are you already retired?</label>
          <div class="yes-no-buttons-container">
            <ul id="are-you-already-retired-list" class="yes-no-buttons-list">
              <li class="left-button">
                <a id="yes-retired-button" class="button-text">Yes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="right-button">
                <a id="no-retired-button" class="button-text">No</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <small></small>
        </div>

      <!-- RETIREMENT DATE -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="date-of-retirement" class="form-text" id="date-of-retirement-label">Date of
            Retirement</label>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input type="date" class="form-text date" id="date-of-retirement" name="date-of-retirement"
                   required
                   aria-required="true" placeholder="  dd/mm/yyyy">
              <div id="retirement-date-icon-div" class="icon-button-container icon-div">
                  <button class="btn icon-button" type="button" id="retirement-date-icon-button"> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt details-icon"></i></button>
              </div>
            <small></small>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
      <!-- ARE YOU IN TRANSITION TO RETIREMENT-->
      <div class="col-sm form-field form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="are-you-in-transition-list" class="form-text">Are You in Transition to
            Retirement?</label>
          <div class="yes-no-buttons-container">
            <ul id="are-you-in-transition-list" class="yes-no-buttons-list">
              <li class="left-button">
                <a id="yes-in-transition-button" class="button-text">Yes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="right-button">
                <a id="no-in-transition-button" class="button-text">No</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <small></small>
        </div>

      <!-- ARE YOU A HOMEOWNER -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="are-you-homeowner-list" class="form-text">Are you a homeowner?</label>
          <div class="yes-no-buttons-container">
            <ul id="are-you-homeowner-list" class="yes-no-buttons-list">
              <li class="left-button">
                <a id="yes-homeowner-button" class="button-text">Yes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="right-button">
                <a id="no-homeowner-button" class="button-text">No</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <small></small>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
      <!-- FORTNIGHTLY RENT -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="fortnightly-rent" class="form-text" id="fortnightly-rent-label">Fortnightly Rent</label>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input type="number" aria-valuemin="0" min="0" aria-valuemax="9000" max="9000"
                   class="input-text whole-number" id="fortnightly-rent" name="fortnightly-rent"
                   onKeyDown="if (this.value.length == 4) this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);"/>
            <small></small>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- DATE YOU WILL CEASE RENTING -->
      <div class="col-sm form-field form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="date-rent-ceases" class="form-text">Date rent ceases (optional)</label>
          <div class="form-field">
            <input type="date" class="form-text date" id="date-rent-ceases" name="date-rent-ceases"
                   placeholder="  dd/mm/yyyy">
              <div id="date-rent-ceases-icon-div" class="icon-button-container icon-div">
                  <button class="btn icon-button" type="button" id="date-rent-ceases-icon-button"> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt details-icon"></i></button>
              </div>
              <div id="refresh-calendar-icon-div" class="icon-button-container icon-div">
                <button class="btn icon-button" type="button"  id="refresh-calendar-icon-button"> <i class="fas fa-undo details-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
            <small></small>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
      <!-- ARE YOU SINGLE AND SHARING-->
      <div class="col-sm form-field-bottom-gap">
          <label for="are-you-single-and-sharing-list" class="form-text">Are you single and sharing?</label>
          <div class="yes-no-buttons-container">
            <ul id="are-you-single-and-sharing-list" class="yes-no-buttons-list">
              <li class="left-button">
                <a id="yes-single-and-sharing-button" class="button-text">Yes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="right-button">
                <a id="no-single-and-sharing-button" class="button-text">No</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <small></small>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm form-field-bottom-gap">
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->

</form>
```

Comment: Please provide your html to check

Comment: How do I put the html code into a comment so that it looks like code?

Comment: I realised I just needed to edit the original question.  All done.

Comment: How about `document.elementFromPoint(left, top)?.closest( 'form' )?.id`? The element at the point _might not be a form with ID at all_, but an input or span or text inside it, so search for the closest form parent and select that?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using closest so I found another way to do it using the position of the form relative to the window scroll position.  I had a header and dropdown menu above the form which had to be taken into account.  What I was trying to do was get the form the user was currently scrolled to and display the name of that form in the header above the form container so the user could see where they were.  I have posted my solution answer to my own question.

Comment: Please show us the actual rendered HTML for your form(s) - it looks a lot like your forms do NOT have a unique ID, but we can't tell for sure from server-side code.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  In my original question I added the html code for one of the forms.  I have created a separate jsp file for each form and each one has a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution which used the $(window).scrollTop() and $(el).position().top to figure out how far the element is from the top of the screen after scrolling.

[How to find the closest element to the current position with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760567/how-to-find-the-closest-element-to-the-current-position-with-jquery)

Here is my solution which modifies the above solution slightly taking into account the elements above the form container and changing the form scrolled to when it reaches the top of the container on scrolling down and when half the previous form is in view when scrolling upwards.

```js
function updateFormTextAtScrolledPosition(){

    let detailsBannerHeight = $("#details-dropdown-div").outerHeight();
    let headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight()

    let names = [];
    $("form").each(function() {
        let f = $(this);
        let formHeight = f.outerHeight();
        if (f.is(":visible")) {
            let formScrollPosition = f.position().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (formScrollPosition <= detailsBannerHeight + headerHeight && formScrollPosition > 0) {
                let index = getFormIdIndex(f.attr('id'));
                updateDetailsText(index);
            }
        }
    });
}
```